# With GTK+ 3, how can I make a GtkScale trigger "value-changed" on mouse release?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I have a `GtkScale` and I'd like it to only fire `value-changed` events when mouse button is release, i.e. not while you're dragging the scale around.

In GTK+ 2, there was a function called `gtk_range_set_update_policy` which could be called with:

```
gtk_range_set_update_policy(scale, GTK_UPDATE_DISCONTINUOUS)
```

But that function has been removed. Any idea on how to do this with GTK+ 3?

(The project I'm working on is in Python with PyGObject, but answers in C or (most) other languages is ok.)

Comment: Then why not connect to `button-release-event` instead? You can get the value in the `button-release-event callback` and perform the operation you did in the `value-change` callback

Comment: Thanks anon! That's a good suggestion. But I still want to get a signal when the value has been changed through other means, i.e. by keyboard actions.  I'd rather not reimplement all the GtkScale functionality in a key-press event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I got it now. Pretty obvious now that I know what to do. Thanks to anonymous who pointed my in the right direction!

On `button-press-event`, I set a flag that avoids my `value-change` code (actually I switched to use the `change-value` event instead). On `button-release-event` I unset it. Obvious. :-)

Comment: thanks a lot for the tip, as i've been wondering the same thing and will probably be implementing this soon using `gtkmm`! but... ugh, is this really what we're reduced to? having to waste bytes storing and time manipulating a custom flag for this on each of our `range`s, for each mouse event... when it used to be a native api feature? thanks a ton, gtk. commit ref: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-January/msg01174.html